# T-SQL query to select from one table and insert into another

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Please read the question before marking this as a duplicate.

I am trying to insert a row into a table with 5 columns. I want 3 of those columns to come from another table, which I will read using a select query.

```
INSERT INTO tbl.Log (
     LogDate,
     Object,
     Count,
     Creator,
     LastUpdate)
SELECT TOP 1 
     GETUTCDATE(),
     Object,
     Count, -- I need to +1 to this
     'John Smith',
     LastUpdate
FROM tbl.Objects
WHERE ObjectID = '123'
ORDER BY LastUpdate DESC
```

I can see what I am doing wrong here:

- `GETUTCDATE()` should not go in the SELECT because it is not a column name. Where does it go instead?
- The same is true for `'John Smith'` as creator
- The Count column is an int; I need to read the existing number and add one to it before inserting it.

I could do this manually by performing two separate queries and parsing the data from the `SELECT` into the `INSERT` query, but I am trying to improve my SQL.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your SQL. As for `Count`, you could set `IDENTITY` on the column or use a `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ?.As Chris mentioned,if count is an issue,make it an IDENTITY  column

Comment: Did you even try that or did you just assume it would fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select values that are not a part of your table and do arithmetic on columns during `insert`.

```
INSERT INTO tbl.Log (
     LogDate,
     Object,
     Count,
     Creator,
     LastUpdate)
SELECT TOP 1 
     GETUTCDATE(),
     Object,
     Count+1
     'John Smith',
     LastUpdate
FROM tbl.Objects
WHERE ObjectID = '123'
ORDER BY LastUpdate DESC
```

Understand that the idea of doing the `insert` with two separate queries would result in 2 rows.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with selecting values that doesn't exist on the table, every RDBMS accepts it.

Also, what do you mean by count+1 ? The count that is inside the log table? If so:

```
INSERT INTO tbl.Log (
     LogDate,
     Object,
     Count,
     Creator,
     LastUpdate)
SELECT TOP 1 
     GETUTCDATE(),
     Object,
     (SELECT MAX(Count) FROM tbl.log), 
     'John Smith',
     LastUpdate
FROM tbl.Objects
WHERE ObjectID = '123'
ORDER BY LastUpdate DESC
```

If you meant the count that on the `Objects` table, that replace the sub select with `count+1` , but that just seems like you could have done it your self.